# Business Validation with ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator with complex type model

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

In my blazor server application i have done business validation based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#business-logic-validation)

```
   @page "/"
   @inherits IndexBase
   <EditForm Model="@MyModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidator @ref="customValidator" />
    <ValidationSummary />
      <div>
        <InputText @bind-Value="MyModel.Customer.Name"></InputText>
        <ValidationMessage For="()=>MyModel.Customer.Name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="MyModel.Customer.Age"> </InputNumber>
        <ValidationMessage For="()=>MyModel.Customer.Age" />
      </div>
      <button Text="Save" type="submit">Get Result</button>
    </EditForm>
```

and its base class conatains

```
    public class IndexBase:ComponentBase
     {
       protected MyModel MyModel { get; set; } = new MyModel();
       protected CustomValidator customValidator;
       protected void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
        customValidator.ClearErrors();
        var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        if ( MyModel.Customer.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("a"))
        {
            errors.Add("Customer.Age", new List<string>() { "Age should be greater than 10" });
        }
        if (errors.Count() > 0)
        {
            customValidator.DisplayErrors(errors);
        }
        else
        {
            // Process the form
        }
    }
}
```

and MyModel looks like

```
     public class MyModel
      {
        [ValidateComplexType]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; } = new Customer();
      }

public class Customer
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }0
}
```

and my CustomValidator looks like below code (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#validator-components))

```
         public class CustomValidator : ComponentBase
         {
          private ValidationMessageStore messageStore;

       [CascadingParameter]
       private EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; }

       protected override void OnInitialized()
       {
        if (CurrentEditContext == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"{nameof(CustomValidator)} requires a cascading " +
                $"parameter of type {nameof(EditContext)}. " +
                $"For example, you can use {nameof(CustomValidator)} " +
                $"inside an {nameof(EditForm)}.");
        }

        messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(CurrentEditContext);

        CurrentEditContext.OnValidationRequested += (s, e) =>
            messageStore.Clear();
        CurrentEditContext.OnFieldChanged += (s, e) =>
            messageStore.Clear(e.FieldIdentifier);
    }

    public void DisplayErrors(Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors)
    {
        foreach (var err in errors)
        {
            FieldIdentifier x = CurrentEditContext.Field(err.Key);
            messageStore.Add(x, err.Value);
        }

        CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }

    public void ClearErrors()
    {
        messageStore.Clear();
        CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
    }
}
```

When i click submit button validation code works, but does not adding **modified invalid** class to input control. So this does not display error message and red border to control

Answer (score 0):

I can do like this..

```cs
protected void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    customValidator.ClearErrors();
    var errors = new Dictionary<FieldIdentifier, List<string>>();
    if ( MyModel.Customer.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("a"))
    {
        errors.Add(new FieldIdentifier(MyModel.Customer, "Name"), new 
        List<string> { "Age should be greater than 10" });
    }
    if (errors.Count() > 0)
    {
        customValidator.DisplayErrors(errors);
    }
    else
    {
        // Process the form
    }
}
```

and changed the parameter type in `DisplayErrors` method like this,

```cs
public void DisplayErrors(Dictionary<FieldIdentifier, List<string>> errors)
{
    foreach (var err in errors)
    {
        messageStore.Add(err.Key, err.Value);
    }
    CurrentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
}
```